# Unable to start rabbitmq-server on centos7

Tags: rabbitmq

I installed RabbitMQ on centos7, but when I start the server I get a warning:

```
Warning: PID file not written; -detached was passed.
```

then I check the status of rabbitmq server I get such message

```
centos Error: unable to perform an operation on node 'rabbit@ecs-8767'. Please see diagnostics information and suggestions below.

Most common reasons for this are:

* Target node is unreachable (e.g. due to hostname resolution, TCP connection or firewall issues)
* CLI tool fails to authenticate with the server (e.g. due to CLI tool's Erlang cookie not matching that of the server)
* Target node is not running

In addition to the diagnostics info below:

* See the CLI, clustering and networking guides on https://rabbitmq.com/documentation.html to learn more
* Consult server logs on node rabbit@ecs-8767
* If target node is configured to use long node names, don't forget to use --longnames with CLI tools

DIAGNOSTICS
```

Comment: Check if the port `5672` is free. If you are starting the `management UI` as well, check if the port `15672` is free as well.

Comment: the port 5672 is free,and I try the command "rabbitmq-server start", it show "Failed to write pid file"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your user have a permission to write folder `/var/run`? If the user doesn't have a permission, you can try to start with `sudo`.

Also you can try another method in this link:
https://serverfault.com/questions/159334/what-permissions-are-needed-to-write-a-pid-file-in-var-run/159349#159349